# dnu restore : unable to restore all packages

Tags: asp.net-core, dnu

When trying to restore packages, I am getting this error

```
Error: FindPackagesById: System.Net.Http
  Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
  GET https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetlitedev/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates'
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.security.principal/index.json
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.authentication.cookies/1.0.0-beta8/microsoft.aspnet.authentication.cookies.1.0.0-beta8.nupkg
  GET https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetlitedev/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Runtime.Extensions'
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.Restore.NuGet.HttpSource.<GetAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.Restore.NuGet.NuGetv2Feed.<FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore>d__25.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RemoteWalkProvider.<FindLibrary>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreOperations.<FindLibrary>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreOperations.<FindLibraryByVersion>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreOperations.<FindLibraryMatch>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreOperations.<FindLibraryEntry>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreOperations.<CreateGraphNode>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreOperations.<CreateGraphNode>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreOperations.<CreateGraphNode>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreCommand.<CreateGraphNode>d__71.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreCommand.<RestoreForProject>d__69.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreCommand.<>c__DisplayClass68_0.<<Execute>b__2>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreCommand.<Execute>d__68.MoveNext()
----------
Restore failed
Error: FindPackagesById: System.Diagnostics.Debug
```

This is how my Nuget.config looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<packageSources>
    <add key="AspNetVNext" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetlitedev/api/v2" />
    <add key="NuGet" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="api.nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="Roslyn" value="https://www.myget.org/F/roslyn-nightly/" />
    <add key="DotNet" value="https://www.myget.org/F/dotnet-corefx/" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
    <add key="Smarsh" value="http://nuget.smarshdev.com/nuget/Default" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

You Have an invalid feed.

Probably this feed is invalid
https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetlitedev/api/v2/FindPackagesById and if you do not ignore these errors dnu will fail.

See for option dnu restore -?
Remove the invalid feed from your nuget config.

You can also check the feeds in visual studio 2015. In

```
  Tools-Nuget package manager-Manage nuget packages for solutions
```

Select a package source and look which one generate a 404

You can also copy and past the link in the browser.

The message from this link https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetlitedev/api/v2

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">Feed does not exist.</string>
```

Comment: That is a valid feed as mentioned in this [link](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Configuring-the-feed-used-by-dnu-to-restore-packages). I can see many packages are getting restored from that feed.

Comment: That feed doesn't exist anymore. If you want the latest bits produced by the CI server, use https://myget.org/F/aspnetcidev/api/v2